# How to fetch data on Firebase from time to time?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am fetching data on Firebase from time to time because I am tracking someone's GPS. That someone is saving his location in an interval of 5 minutes so that I can track his GPS. But my problem is how do I fetch data from Firebase with an interval of 5 minutes too?

Or is there any possible way other than this?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if someone is updating his/her location in every five minutes, then you really don't have to run a `CounterDownTimer` in your side to track the location in every five minutes. So I think you just need to add a listener to that node at Firebase that you want to track.

So here's a simple implementation for you. Copied from [Firebase Tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-start)

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog/posts");
// Attach an listener to read the data at our posts reference
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

I'm copying quotes from there too. So that you know it serves your purpose.

> This method will be called anytime new data is added to our Firebase
>   reference, and we don't need to write any extra code to make this
>   happen.

So each time the person you want to track will update his/her location, you'll get a callback in the method stated above and will take necessary action. You really don't have to implement a polling mechanism to do the tracking. That's the way Firebase works actually.

Comment: yes, answer is working fine. but instead of adding we need only to update the data. Is there a method for that?

Comment: This callback method will be called in update case too. The name is confusing though.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll give an example. I tried to change/update the latitude and longitude of one particular child on `Firebase` and while checking on the running app, instead of removing the old marker and display the current marker. both of them will be displayed. but if i am going to force close the app and open it again, the marker displays the curret marker :)
i hope you understand heheh

Comment: Yes, if you reopen the application, it'll display the current marker which is updated as there's no reference of previous marker unless you save it in your local database. That's should the be usual behaviour btw. If you want to show both of them, you need to put as another entry in Firebase too.

Comment: anyone know the underlying how this firebase method works?, did they use special protocol or using interval fetch?

Answer (score 1):

No Needs to put any kind of service of Scheduler to retrieve data from firebase.

As Firebase provide realtime database .. whenever you push your data on Firebase Database the listener will trigger and you can retrieve your data..

Implement following Listener, using this you can retrieve your data whenever database get update.

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


ValueEventListener yourModelListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get YOURMODEL object and use the values to update the UI
        YourModel mModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(YourModel.class);
        Log.e("Data : ",""+mModel);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

    }
};

mDatabase.addValueEventListener(yourModelListener);
```

For More Info about Listeners .. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data